# Wildfly won't start with parse exception error

Tags: mysql, xml, jboss, wildfly

What am I missing where? I have added the mysql-connector with `module.xml` in the `Wildfly_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main` folder. When I start wildfly I get this error (debain with wildfly):

```
11:09:58,289 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception        during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676:    Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:11    2) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331) [wildfly-server-    8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:256)     [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[168,17]
Message: JBAS014789: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0}managed-    executor-services' encountered
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ParseUtils.unexpectedElement(ParseUtils.java:85)     [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at     org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerParser_2_0.readElement(DeploymentScannerParser_2_0.java:121)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerParser_2_0.readElement(DeploymentScannerPars    er_2_0.java:50)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1131) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:458) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:145) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:10    4) [wildfly-controller-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 3 more

11:09:58,294 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has   failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

And here is my `standalone.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.1">

<extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
    <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
</extensions>


<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
    <audit-log>
        <formatters>
            <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
        </formatters>
        <handlers>
            <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
        </handlers>
        <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
            <handlers>
                <handler name="file"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
    </audit-log>
    <management-interfaces>
        <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
            <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
        </http-interface>
    </management-interfaces>
    <access-control provider="simple">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
</management>

<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
        <job-repository>
            <in-memory/>
        </job-repository>
        <thread-pool>
            <max-threads count="10"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
               </datasource>
            <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pincidents" pool-name="pincidents_mysql" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://ip address/pincidents</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user</user-name>
                    <password>pwd</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
             <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <managed-executor-services>
                <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
            </managed-executor-services>
            <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
            </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
        </concurrent>
        <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
        <session-bean>
            <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
            <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
        </session-bean>
        <pools>
            <bean-instance-pools>
                <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
            </bean-instance-pools>
        </pools>
        <caches>
            <cache name="simple"/>
            <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
        </caches>
        <passivation-stores>
            <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
        </passivatiot-stores>
        <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
            <data-stores>
                <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </data-stores>
        </timer-service>
        <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <default-security-domain value="other"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
        <thread-pools>
            <thread-pool name="default">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </thread-pools>
        <default-security-domain value="other"/>
        <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
        <worker name="default"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
            <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
        <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
        <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
        <default-workmanager>
            <short-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </short-running-threads>
            <long-running-threads>
                <core-threads count="50"/>
                <queue-length count="50"/>
                <max-threads count="50"/>
                <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
            </long-running-threads>
        </default-workmanager>
        <cached-connection-manager/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
        <remoting-connector/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
        <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
        <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
            <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
        </mail-session>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
        <endpoint worker="default"/>
        <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
        <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
        <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
        <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
            <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
            </pre-handler-chain>
        </endpoint-config>
        <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
</profile>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
```

Comment: It is hard to check where the error is emanating from as your code have no line numbers, check what is on line being mentioned and the column `[row,col]:[168,17]` i.e line number 168 and column 17. Also the file name is `standalone.xml` and not `standale.xml`.

Comment: It is the first subsystem after the datasources : <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0"> I fixed the name in the problem description. Thanks for showing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It was a tag issue in the tag mentioned above, the   didnt hava a partner